# Unable to load .css file images in Jenkins

Tags: css, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After following up below URL I have successfully added .css file and everything seems fine until I logout. What I witnessed was, Once I logged out from Jenkins page I am not able to see my css file Images.

Jenkins Version- 1.651.3

Simple Theme Plugin Version = 0.3

http://afonsof.com/jenkins-material-theme/

After Login My Jenkins Page

[image]

After Logout

[image]

Error Logs

```
INFO: Completed initialization
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@72d6be85: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Jul 31 10:21:36 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@72d6be85]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@189572bb
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@189572bb: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7137ea0e: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Jul 31 10:21:36 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7137ea0e]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66bdeda2
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:36 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66bdeda2: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo newHostInfo
WARNING: Could not intialize the host network interface on nullbecause of an error: ip-10-10-1: ip-10-10-1: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1: ip-10-10-1: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1496)
        at javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo.newHostInfo(HostInfo.java:75)
        at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.<init>(JmDNSImpl.java:407)
        at javax.jmdns.JmDNS.create(JmDNS.java:60)
        at hudson.DNSMultiCast$1.call(DNSMultiCast.java:32)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-10-1: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:922)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1316)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1492)
        ... 9 more

Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jul 31, 2017 10:21:37 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Comment: You might be missing the stylesheet on the login page. Any errors in console?

Comment: Attached error logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give OverAll Read permissions to Anonymous user.